# Delete android launcher and replace it with my own

Tags: android, replace, launcher

I have an app which I want to use instead of the standard android launcher. When I start my device I want it to show up instead of the launcher. I noticed this was possible and it works except if I press the "Home" button both my launcher app and the standard android app are shown. I want to delete the launcher from my tablet either programatically or manually so the only app I can use the tablet for is my launcher app. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Otherwise this would be a huge security risk. If the user checks the checkbox "Always use" (I think), that dialog won't appear again.

Comment: I understand. But, this is my tablet so I could delete the files from it manually. Can't I just delete the standard launcher and in it's path put my own app ?

Comment: You could do this with Root rights (remounting System read-write, cd to the system apps directory, make backup from launcher, delete it).
But your users will hate you for that and you will get a lot of 1-star  ratings ;-)

Comment: Like I said, the device MUST be rooted, in order to remount the System read-write. And users won't like it. So its better to display a toast telling them to check the checkbox.

Comment: Indeed I find this to be true. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be rooted.

1. Open fx (make sure you have the root add-on)
2. Go to system/custpack/unremovable/withoutlibs
3. Delete the launcher apk